# How to create a D3 time scale for all hours in a month

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a D3 time scale for all the hours in any given month which can then be used as my x axis. The timeScale function should map input dates onto the range of hours but doesn't currently do so. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```js
    var hourRange = d3.timeHour.range(new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date(2018, 1, 1));

    var timeScale1 = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date(2018, 0, 31)])
        .range(hourRange);

    var temp1 = timeScale1(new Date(2018, 0, 20));

    console.log(temp1.toISOString());
```

Based on the comment from Gerardo code should be:

```js
    var timeScale1 = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date(2018, 0, 31)])
        .range(0, 700);

    var temp1 = timeScale1(new Date(2018, 0, 20));

    console.log(temp1); // 443.3333333333333 (pixels)
```

Comment: So do you want to have around 720 ticks in your axis? That's almost 1 tick per 2 pixels in a typical laptop screen.

Comment: It may end up being one tick every 6 hours for example. Just as long as the hour in each datum gets mapped correctly by the scale.

Comment: I was on my mobile when I made the comment above, and only now I'm properly seeing your code. It has a fundamental problem: the `range` has to be the coordinates in the SVG space, where the axis will be painted, not a time array.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks for pointing that out.